# Using Spring with WebSphere 8.5.5 and Apache Wink - web.xml error on server startup

Tags: java, spring, web.xml, websphere-8, apache-wink

I'm currently migrating a Java app using Wink 1.1.1 and Spring 3.1.2 from WAS 7 to WAS 8.5.5.  I'm trying to use the native Wink-integration that is available in WAS 8.5 instead of using the separate Wink jars we currently have now with WAS 7.

I'm getting an error on server startup that looks like this:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [META-INF/server/wink-core-context.xml] cannot be opened because it
>   does not exist    at
>   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)

Now, in my current WAS 7 world where I'm explicitly using the Wink jars I have this entry in my web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Wink Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:META-INF/server/wink-core-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-configuration.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

which works just fine.

I'm trying to figure out the correct web.xml entry for WAS 8.5 using the native Wink-integration that it has.  Here is what I currently have:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>IBM Rest Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:META-INF/server/wink-core-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-configuration.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

However, I'm getting the error above.  I'm wondering if the Wink core context file is simply located at a different place in the IBM setup?  Also, which jar in the IBM setup actually houses the wink implementation?  I haven't been able to find a definitive answer on that either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247567/error-invoking-restful-webservice-on-websphere-8-5-5-2-server/30714543#30714543

Comment: Yep, I have already have everything completed in the answer on that post.  My main question is what should the web.xml entry look like above when integrating with Spring?

Comment: This article talks about Spring Integration with wink: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-apachewink2/

you can also try using RestServlet Instead of IBMRestServlet.

Comment: where is "wink-core-context.xml" is packaged ? inside EAR or WAR?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that link as well.  This portion: 

 _To load the Spring context, you must first define and add the context load listener to the web.xml file of the Web application. Also, the contextConfigLocation context-param should indicate the location of the Apache Wink core context file and the application-specific context file._

actually led me to my question above.  I'm trying to find out exactly where that Apache WInk core context file is...and what it is called.

Comment: Have you included "wink-spring-support-<version_no>-incubating.jar" in the classpath? If not then this could be the issue.

Comment: Is that an Apache Wink jar or an IBM specific jar?

Comment: Its Apace wink jar. Download the 1.1 version.

Comment: Easy now Prerak; I just had a chance to test it!  :)  And yes, it did work!  That eliminated the error shown above.  I do have another error now however, but I will post that into a different question.  If you could look for another question coming soon I would appreciate it!  Thanks for help; if you post the inclusion of the wink-spring-support.jar as an answer I'll mark it and give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **wink-spring-support-1.1-incubating.jar** is not supplied with WAS 8.5 Wink Distribution, you need to include that jar explicitly in application classpath.